# Will downgrading AWS RDS instance storage type and backup retention period cause downtime and data loss?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance (db.t2.small) with Storage type Provisioned IOPS(SSD) and with backup retention period of 2 days.

I want to change the storage type to General Purpose(SSD) and change the backup retention period to 30 days.

If I do this changes will the instance have any downtime? 
If yes how long will the downtime be? 
Am I going to face any data loss?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, you will have downtime since the server instance type is changing and reboot will be required - not certain the amount of downtime, but guesstimate would be 10-30 minutes at most.

No, there will be no data loss.

Comment: The original question is about changing the instance storage type, not the instance type.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the change in storage type, according to AWS documentation, RDS tries to keep the data volume and DB instance alive and serving requests, however performance can degrade significantly.  It's possible that performance degradation is so common and severe, that it might as well be offline.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.ModifyingExisting

> Whenever you change the storage type of a DB instance, the data for
>   that DB instance is migrated to a new volume. The duration of the
>   migration depends on several factors such as database load, storage
>   size, storage type, and amount of IOPS provisioned (if any). Typical
>   migration times are under 24 hours, but can take up to several days in
>   some cases. During the migration, the DB instance is available for
>   use, but might experience performance degradation.

Regarding the change in backup retention, I tried changing it on my RDS (PostgreSQL) from 0 to 7 and it rebooted the instance and put it into a modifying state, but it still responded to queries.  I have almost 0 load on my RDS servers, so I can't say how responsive it would be while in this state, but I would think changing the backup retention period wouldn't be something that would affect the database itself very much.

Answer (score 2):

I did a downgrade on a r3.4xlarge with postgres 9.3, 3TB db with 10K provisioned iops to general purpose SSDs. Took 14 hours to finish, there was no performance impact (because I get 9K iops for the 3TB, and we werent using anything close to that). The conversion used up approx 1000 read iops and 1000 write iops.

Comment: Just to check - you didn't experience  downtime, correct?

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Assuming no downtime from when he/she said `there was no performance impact`